# Avoid Overlay on specific pages using PDFBox

Tags: java, spring, pdf, overlay, pdfbox

I have created a Sample.pdf with 4 pages in it, and have added some content into the pdf.
I have another PDF(template.pdf) which is of 2 pages only containing some border lines and images.
I want to Overlay template.pdf with Sample.pdf such that, that the contents from template.pdf will be overlayed on first 2 pages of Sample.pdf , and the remaining pages will only have the original content.

But when i try to implement the overlay from PDFBox, the border and images gets repeated again, i.e on first two pages the border and images comes properly, but on 3rd and 4th page also the border comes which shouldnt.

Below is my method for implementing such,

```
void overlayPDF(){
try {
            PDDocument overlayDoc = PDDocument.load(new File("D:\\template.pdf"));    
            Overlay overlayObj = new Overlay();    
            PDDocument originalDoc = PDDocument.load(new File("D:\\Sample.pdf"));
            
            overlayObj.setOverlayPosition(Overlay.Position.BACKGROUND);
            overlayObj.setInputPDF(originalDoc);
            overlayObj.setAllPagesOverlayPDF(overlayDoc);
            Map<Integer, String> ovmap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();            
            ovmap.put(1, "D:\\template.pdf");
            ovmap.put(2, "D:\\template.pdf");

            overlayObj.overlay(ovmap);
                        
            originalDoc.save("D:\\Sample.pdf");        
            overlayDoc.close();
            originalDoc.close();            
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Also im little bit confused in how the overlay.overlay works and how we should enter the map values in it.

I know something in code is missing , if someone can help me that would be great,
Also i know i can convert template.pdf to images and then i can add those images to respective pages of Sample.pdf, but i dont want to convert then into images

Comment: There's a bug in 2.0.27 with `overlay(ovmap);`, please try with 2.0.26 (or 2.0.25, not sure). Or with the snapshot https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/2.0.28-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: Also you've set `setAllPagesOverlayPDF()` so the map is disregarded anyway.

Comment: I tried usinf your recommended version, but still same issue, can you suggest me which method i should use instead of setAllPagesOverlayPDF(), so that i can apply overlay on 1st and 2nd page of sample.pdf

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
void overlayPDF(){
try {
            PDDocument overlayDoc = PDDocument.load(new File("D:\\template.pdf"));    
            Overlay overlayObj = new Overlay();    
            PDDocument originalDoc = PDDocument.load(new File("D:\\Sample.pdf"));
            
            overlayObj.setOverlayPosition(Overlay.Position.BACKGROUND);
            overlayObj.setInputPDF(originalDoc);
            overlayObj.setAllPagesOverlayPDF(overlayDoc);
            Map<Integer, String> ovmap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();            
            ovmap.put(1, "D:\\template.pdf");


            overlayObj.overlay(ovmap);
                        
            originalDoc.save("D:\\Sample.pdf");        
            overlayDoc.close();
            originalDoc.close();            
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: I tried with version 2.0.26 also and used  your code, but the overlay is coming on all pages of sample.pdf, and i want to overlay 1st and 2nd page of sample.pdf only

Comment: try this ovmap.put(1, "D:\\Sample.pdf");
 ovmap.put(2, "D:\\Sample.pdf");

Comment: tried this as well, isnt working

Comment: what happened this time

Comment: it applied on which pages

Comment: it's applying on all 4 pages of sample.pdf and only first page of template.pdf is getting overlayed on all 4 pages of sample.pdf

Comment: if you avoid this: ovmap.put(2, "D:\\Sample.pdf");  then see is the overlay applied on two pages only.

Comment: if i avoid using ovmap.put(...) then still overlay is applied to all pages of sample.pdf such that 1st and 2nd page of sample.pdf will have 1st and 2nd page of template.pdf overlayed respectively, And the last 2 pages of sample.pdf will again be overlayed with 1st and 2nd page of template.pdf

Comment: just write: ovmap.put(1, "D:\\Sample.pdf");  this much only

Comment: Tried already, doesnt give expected result

Comment: what it giving now

Comment: try this method setDefaultOverlayPDF

Comment: template.pdf's 1st pg is overlayed on all pages of smaple.pdf and setDefaultOverlayPDF also doesnt work

Comment: can you share the git hub link i will try on my own